# Collections.unmodifiableMap API : Any performance overhead in case of frequent updates to parent Map?

Tags: java, collections

I am planning to use [unmodifiableMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) API from Collections class.

I am using this API to restrict other classes to modify my  parent`Map` object.

I know that this API is better than creating new copy of Map but still I have doubts on performance in case of frequent updates.

If my parent map gets modified frequently - `50K times per day`(with both put and remove calls), does this `unmodifiableMap` API adds any additional overhead to performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, 50K modifications per day is not that much. It's on average less than one per second.

Secondly, `unmodifiableMap()` only returns a view to the original map. It adds an insignificant overhead to accessing the values of the original map, but it doesn't affect modifications made directly to the original map.

Thirdly, worrying about micro-optimization is not a good way to ensure performance. Guessing whether something affects performance in a *meaningful* way is about as effective as copy pasting code snippets from StackOverflow answers randomly in order to get a working program. Use a profiler when you need to find what's making your program slow, don't try to plan ahead with what amounts to nanosecond (if even that) savings.